# "para poder nos unirmos novamente" ou "para podermos nos unir novamente"?

Tags: português-brasileiro, gramática, verbos, conjugações, concordância-verbal

Vinha eu caminhando pela rua quando me deparei com o seguinte cartaz:

> O isolamento é necessário **para poder nos unirmos** novamente.

A frase soou estranha aos meus ouvidos e tentei a opção "o isolamento é necessário **para podermos nos unir** novamente".  Achei esta segunda opção mais natural, embora eu prefira "o isolamento é necessário para que possamos nos unir novamente".

Tratando-se de um cartaz do governo municipal, fiquei em dúvida quanto à gramaticalidade e aceitabilidade da frase.

Pergunto então: as duas formas estão gramaticalmente corretas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema dessa frase é uma construção com o semiauxiliar *poder* ter o verbo principal flexionado, em vez de *poder*. Seria como dizer *a faca é necessária para ir matarmos o Carlos*. Portanto:

> O isolamento é necessário para **podermos unir-nos** novamente.

ou

> O isolamento é necessário para **nos podermos unir** novamente.

ou

> O isolamento é necessário para **podermo-nos unir** novamente.

Em português do Brasil *para podermos nos unir* também é possível.

Answer (score 2):

A primeira opção, "para poder nos unirmos" me parece incorreta por apresentar um erro de concordância, como apontou ANeves em sua [resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/7747/2764): quem poderá seremos "nós". Portanto a segunda opção não apenas soa melhor, como é a correta:

> O isolamento é necessário para podermos nos unir novamente.

É possível ter "poder" concordando com "isolamento", mas alterando o sentido da frase, e.g., "O isolamento é longo para poder nos unir." (ou seja, para ter efeito).

A alternativa "O isolamento é necessário para que possamos nos unir novamente." me parece preferível no sentido de ser mais clara, mas tem também menos impacto, portanto é menos adequada para um cartaz.

Answer (score 1):

Eu também acho que a frase tem um problema de concordância... "de pessoa"?

> O isolamento é necessário para *poder nos unirmos novamente.

Qual seria o sujeito de "poder"?
O único que me parece natural é "nós":

- O isolamento é necessário para que **nós** possamos nos unir novamente.

Então, a frase teria de ter concordância na conjugação:

> O isolamento é necessário para [nós] *podermos nos unir* novamente.

E não sei explicar isto com gramaticalidade, mas quando mudamos o poder para podermos, o unirmos *tem* de mudar para unir.

Comment: Sou capaz de ter atropelado o "que nós possamos nos unir"... não tenho a certeza como isto fica na forma brasileira, desculpem. :) Do lado de cá do Atlântico ficaria "que nós nos possamos unir".

Answer (score -1):

Nenhuma das duas parece correcta, mas a primeira é desastrosa.

Julgo que o correto seria: para nos podermos unir.

Comment: Porquê? Explica ao Centaurus porque achas isso, para ele ficar mais convencido :) - mesmo que a explicação seja só "porque me soa melhor assim".